Stick two elements side by side in a Row
In order to show my username and the ability to edit it, I would like to place a text with the username and an IconButton for editing side by side (or with minimal space between them). However, when I put these two elements in a Row, Flutter keeps a space between them that I can't remove.
Here is my code:
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Text(
      "%${userProvider.userAccount?.pseudo}",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
        color: themeProvider.isDarkMode
            ? Colors.white
            : Colors.grey,
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,  
      constraints: BoxConstraints(),  
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.edit, size: 15),
    ),
  ],
)

ResultsImage
Is there a solution to remove or control this space in my code? 

You can resolve the issue by changing the IconButton to an InkWell widget. Here's how you can do it:
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    // Add your onTap functionality here
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.edit, size: 15),
)

